# I want to send voice data sequentially and receive responses sequentially with websocket

Tags: c#, websocket

I'm trying voice recognition with a websocket enabled speech recognition API in C#.
According to this API, if voice data (binary) is sent sequentially, the recognition result at that time will be returned.
I send data continuously with the following code, but I can not get the preliminary recognition result.
Only the final recognition result is obtained.
I think that the part that sends voice data is inappropriate as a cause, but I do not understand how it is wrong.
I do not know so much about websokcet, and I think that there is a strange part in that sending part. Please tell me about the correct sending method.

This is the API I'm using.
https://mimi.readme.io/docs/mimi-websocket-api-spec

(old)

```cs
static async Task Send(ClientWebSocket ws)
        {
            ArraySegment<byte> closingMessage = new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
            "{\"command\": \"recog-break\"}"
            ));
            using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead("voice.raw"))
            {
                byte[] b = new byte[3200];
                while (fs.Read(b, 0, b.Length) > 0)
                {
                    await ws.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(b), WebSocketMessageType.Binary, true, CancellationToken.None);
                }
                await ws.SendAsync(closingMessage, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
            }
        }
```

(new)

```cs
static async Task SendAudio(ClientWebSocket ws)
        {
            ArraySegment<byte> closingMessage = new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
            "{\"command\": \"recog-break\"}"
            ));
            using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead("audio.raw"))
            {
                byte[] b = new byte[3200];
                while (fs.Read(b, 0, b.Length) > 0)
                {
                    await ws.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(b, 0, fs.Read(b, 0, b.Length)), WebSocketMessageType.Binary, true, CancellationToken.None);
                }
                await ws.SendAsync(closingMessage, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
            }
        }
```

(new2)

```
private async Task SendAudio(ClientWebSocket ws)
        {
            ArraySegment<byte> closingMessage = new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
            "{\"command\": \"recog-break\"}"
            ));
            using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead("audio.raw"))
            {
                byte[] b = new byte[3200];
                while (true)
                {
                    int temp = fs.Read(b, 0, b.Length);
                    if (temp == 0)
                        break;
                    await ws.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(b, 0, temp), WebSocketMessageType.Binary, true, CancellationToken.None);

                }
                await ws.SendAsync(closingMessage, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
            }
        }
```

Comment: As a guess, the recognizer gets confused because you send over the entire 3200 byte buffer, not just the part that was read.

Comment: Thank you for comment. To send just the part that was read, how should I do?

Comment: Capture the result of `fs.Read` (the number of bytes read), and then use that as an argument to the `ArraySegment<>` constructor - there's an overload that takes start and length in addition to the source buffer.

Comment: I wrote as follows, but it does not go well. ```await ws.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(b, 0, fs.Read(b, 0, b.Length)), WebSocketMessageType.Binary, true, CancellationToken.None);``` Is this wrong?

Comment: Please update the question with the way the code is now (and keep the old version).

Comment: I see, but I just changed one line.

Comment: That was not enough :) - You now read twice, so there's probably no data left for your second read. Instead, capture the length for the first read and use that in your send call.

Comment: I have rewritten the code. However, again, the result during recognition can not be obtained. Only the final recognition result is obtained :(

Comment: I'm stumped. BTW, how did you come up with 3200?

Comment: When I changed the speech recognition engine (it is possible to select some engines), it worked! I'm sorry to let you take the time. Thank you for taking care of this problem. Thank you very much!!! :)

Comment: No it's fine, it's what we do here :)